# Adding a package causes project to always run in debug mode

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget, nancy

When I build and run my project the following code

```
Console.WriteLine("I am running in debug {0}", StaticConfiguration.IsRunningDebug);
```

Produces ***true*** in **debug** mode and ***false*** in **release** mode, as expected. Then I add a package using nuget, the nuget server is our local nuget server and it is a library that we own and publish.

When I run the above code again again, I get ***true*** in **debug** mode and ***true*** in **release** mode as well.

```
//Get all non-nancy assemblies, and select the custom attributes
var assembliesInDebug
    = AppDomainAssemblyTypeScanner.TypesOf<INancyModule>(ScanMode.ExcludeNancy)
                                  .Select(x => x.Assembly.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DebuggableAttribute), true))
                                  .Where(x => x.Length != 0);

//if there are any, then return the IsJITTrackingEnabled
//else if the collection is empty it returns false
return assembliesInDebug.Any(d => ((DebuggableAttribute)d[0]).IsJITTrackingEnabled
```

);

When I look on the build server it appears as if those libraries are being built in release mode. Any ideas where to look?

**UPDATE:**

I ran the assemblies through the code I found on Scott Hanselman's website to detect if they were built in debug or release mode. Both DLLs that are downloaded are built in **debug** mode for some reason. Despite the call on the build server very specifically stating release mode.

So I am assuming now, that if ANY DLL is built in debug mode that the whole build because debug mode

Comment: Could that value still be true even if built in Release mode? Can you explain why you're using this code, rather than `#if DEBUG return true;`?

Comment: if you are referring to the scan of the assemblies, that comes from the Nancy source code. Some other code is relying on that result

Answer (score 0):

> Adding a package causes project to always run in debug mode

It seems to be an issue for the nuget package `nancy`.

[Nancy (2.0.0-clinteastwood) is a Debug build on net452](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/issues/2897)

Since it is not an officially released version, we may need to wait for an official version to fix this issue, you can follow with your comments and check the feedback of this issue.

Hope this helps.